# Shielded from demotion

Tags: league-of-legends

I just got promoted to a new division. Now I'm having no luck and I lost at least 3 games with 0 LP's.

I got this message:

[image]

What does that mean?

Does that mean that I won't get demoted even if i keep losing games? Or how many games does this shield can me protect from demotion?

Comment: May want to get a friend who you know is good to help carry a game or two in duo queue to get your mmr back up

Comment: @Dragonrage Or just take whatever rank the game thinks you deserve rather than boosting. If it's only luck that the user made it that far, it's sometimes better to go back down a rank and work on improving rather than relying on another player to boost you back up.

Comment: I have been unlucky. 1st time i reach G5. I was able to reach promos for G4 but i lost them and went losing untill reach 0LP's

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will be shielded for 3 games after a division promotion and at least 10 games after a tier promotion regardless of your MMR.

[Source](https://support.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/204010760-Ranked-Play-FAQ#h3q2)

You can still lose more and not get demoted if your MMR is a lot higher than the division you got promoted to.